# How would the world change if cryptocurrencies supersede all conventional bank businesses?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, economy, futurology, currency

What would happen if cryptocurrencies supersede all the current money businesses?

Will economy create a different system to get stabilized anyhow?

**My current approach:**

Due to a lack of financial interest or even interest availability the whole financial system will get challenged in a way of hardened investment policies and therefore a lack of growth.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Dave. As the name suggest, we help solving problem about worldbuilding. We are not a forum to discuss about opinions. Please state your problem, else the question will likely be closed.

Comment: The problem is clearly stated, it suggests to describe a hypothetical world which uses cryptocurrencies alone, which is pretty much worldbuilding.

Comment: As has been said this is not a discussion forum and explicitly asking for "your opinions" on a very broad topic about how the complete world would change without even mentioning a timeframe or specific topic of interest makes me wonder whether this is "opinion-based" or just "too broad". Please try to [edit] your question to narrow it down to a specific, somewhat objectively answerable question. Also, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about the effects on society as a whole of a particular change are almost universally considered to be too broad on Worldbuilding SE, so with your recent edit, this is likely to remain on hold as "too broad". You will have to narrow this down considerably for it to be answerable according to our standards.

Comment: Dave, once again this is not a forum. We don't give opinions, we give answers to questions. Opinions are based to subjective evaluations, answers can be more objectively rated. You, despite the edit, keep asking for opinions!

Comment: This question is like asking what would happen if soccer supersedes the entire sports industry. Sure soccer can become a large part of the sports industry but the game that the players play actually mean very little to the industry as a whole. The industry will continue in pretty much the same way but with more focus on the sport. Even if all transactions are backed by "blockchains" doesn't mean banks or financial services will change, the services they offer are all going to have to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First Option:

No more "bank business" means no more banks. There won't be bank loans -- no more mortgages for home owners, no more financing for companies. No more savings accounts, and all that. **All you have are distributed cryptocurrency accounts, and you can't borrow from those.**

In short notice the technological society that is required to run a cryptocurrency collapses.

## Second Option:

Not much changes for the banks. *Many* people no longer have a bank account, but all the other bank business remains. *Many* people would still have a savings account, even if that is backed by cryptotransactions behind the scenes, because they don't want to keep their key safe -- they trust the professionals at the bank to do that.

The cash economy vanishes, and so does much privacy. The block chains rely on public ledgers and some government (or commercial) organizations could try and start analyzing them. Don't underestimate how much computing power they can bring to bear.

Comment: *"some government (or commercial) organizations"* ...or criminal organizations.